# Is there a way to attach materialized view in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Something failed while we were swapping disks for our ClickHouse database. When ClickHouse started, I had to attach all the tables as they were not there via `ATTACH TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`.

Is there a way to do the same for materialized views? I couldn't find a way how to do that and when I try to create it from scratch (`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS ...`, ClickHouse says:

> Data directory for table already containing data parts - probably it
>   was unclean DROP table or manual intervention. You must either clear
>   directory by hand or use ATTACH TABLE instead of CREATE TABLE if you
>   need to use that parts.

So the files are still there but dunno how to attach the view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the ".inner." table first.

Materialized views do not store data, they create a special table with the engine that you choose when you create the view. The name of that table is ".inner.the_name_of_the_view".

So you need to attach that table first, and then attach the materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

When attaching other tables and restarting the ClickHouse server, the views got attached automatically. I was trying to attach .inner tables too but it didn't let me.